# How to bind a button in the popup with a function call?

Tags: python, binding, kivy, popup, textinput

I have created a notepad kind of application using Kivy, with root file named '**Notes**'. It is divided into a relative layout with 'save' button and a text input field. What i want is, when i click the save button, it will direct to a popup window (root named **Popups**) with a 'text input' field, an 'ok' button and a cancel button. When i click the 'ok' button, i need it to write the text in the main input field to a text file with the text in the popup input field as the filename.

When i run the code, everything's OK, except the **updated** text input is not written to the created text file or the filename. But, if the popup is not used, everything's working fine. Below is my code and its '.kv' file.

The following is the python file, named 'main.py'.

```
from kivy import app
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 10)
Config.set('graphics', 'top', 50)
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 800)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 450)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
Builder.load_file('Note.kv')

from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import os


class Notes(BoxLayout):  # root class
    popup_text = StringProperty('Enter the filename')
    note_text = StringProperty('Write something...')

    def new(self):  # function not defined yet.
        pass

    def save(self):  # the part i am having trouble.
        os.makedirs('Notes', exist_ok=True)
        name = self.popup_text
        file = open('Notes\\%s.txt' % name, 'w')
        file.write(self.note_text)
        file.close()

    def close(self):  # the exit button.
        app.stopTouchApp()


class Notepad(App):
    def build(self):
        return Notes()


Notepad().run()
```

The following is the '.kv' file, named 'Note.kv'.

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<Notes>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    StackLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .2, .2, .2, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
        size_hint: None, None
        width: dp(40)
        height: root.height
        spacing: 10
        RoundButton:
            text: 'New'
            size_hint: None, None
            width: dp(40)
            height: dp(30)
            on_press: root.new()
        RoundButton:
            text: 'Save'
            size_hint: None, None
            width: dp(40)
            height: dp(30)
            on_press: Factory.Popups().open()
        RoundButton:
            text: 'Exit'
            size_hint: None, None
            width: dp(40)
            height: dp(30)
            on_press: root.close()

    TextInput:  # trouble area 1 (the main text input)
        id: The_text
        #background_normal: 'Images/Moon sketch.jpg'
        #background_active: 'Images/Moon sketch blur.jpg'
        background_color: .2, .2, .2
        cursor_color: 1, 1, 1
        cursor_width: 5
        font_size: 21
        foreground_color: 1, 1, 1
        padding: 20, 20, 20, 0
        text: root.note_text
        selection_color: 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, .5
        use_bubble: True
        focus: True

<Popups@Popup>:
    size_hint: .4, .4
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'Save'
    separator_color: .2, .4, .7
    separator_height: 3
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 0
        Label:
            text: 'Save as?'
        TextInput:  # trouble area 2 (popup text input)
            id: The_popup_text
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            size_hint: .8, None
            height: dp(30)
            background_color: .2, .2, .2
            cursor_color: 1, 1, 1
            foreground_color: 1, 1, 1
            multiline: False
            focus: True
            text: Factory.Notes().popup_text
        RelativeLayout:
            RoundButton:
                text: 'OK'
                pos: dp(80), dp(5)
                size_hint: None, None
                width: dp(60)
                height: dp(30)
                on_release:
                    Factory.Notes().save()
                    root.dismiss()
            RoundButton:
                text: 'Cancel'
                pos: dp(150), dp(5)
                size_hint: None, None
                width: dp(60)
                height: dp(30)
                on_release: root.dismiss()

<RoundButton@Button>:  # setting button style
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .2, .4, .7, .7
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: 5, 5, 5, 5
```

I am relatively new to python, kivy and tried youtube and stack results. Nothing worked.

Comment: ask here https://chat.kivy.org/